# Why socket.io acknowledgements differ in server instance and socket instance

Tags: javascript, socket.io

i am using js socket.io library. I use acknowledgement in emit method. If i use socket instance:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket: Socket) {
    socket.emit('test', (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

it will output my response without errors. But if i use server instance:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket: Socket) {
    io.to(socket.id).emit('test', (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

timeout error will be generated. I was trying to fix this by adding

```
.timeout(10000)
```

but acknowledgement function arguments also differ between server and socket instance. In server instance first argument is error, second is all response data; in socket all arguments is response data.
So i had to fix code with server instance:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket: Socket) {
    io.to(socket.id).timeout(10000).emit('test', (err, response) => {
        response = response[0];

        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Why this functions differs? This is error in socket.io library code or I don't understand something?

Comment: We can't answer design decision of library authors

Comment: @Samathingamajig, I asked because i thought that there is the reason for that decision